# How to add 'apply' function to calculate multiple 95th percentile?

Tags: r, lapply

I have 50 items from column 1 to 50. And I would like to calculate 95th percentile for each item to replace the outliers.

I found the quantile function for calcuating specific percentile,
`quantile(data$item1, 0.95)` but it seems like I need to make 50 codes to get 50 different percentile score for each item.

Is there any way to use `apply` or `lapply` fuction to calculate 95th percentile for each item?

I tried following way (I think I definitely wrong!).

```
quantile <- lapply(1:50,
                   function(v) quantile(data[v], probs = 0.95, na.rm = TRUE,
                                        names = FALSE, type = 9, digites = 2))
quantile
```

However, when I compare the result of this function with individually calculating function (`quantile(data$item1, 0.95)`), the numbers were not matched.

Comment: Try it with `data[[v]]` instead of `data[v]`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply()` to your data frame and specify column margins (here `2`):

```
   my_q <- apply(data[1:50], 2, quantile, probs=0.95, na.rm=T)
```

or to give more quantiles (e.g, 50th and 95th):

```
   my_q <- apply(data[1:50], 2, quantile, probs= c(0.50,0.95), na.rm=T)
```